# Stimulsoft Server Designer

Tags: dataset, report, stimulsoft

What I want to achive is me giving a DataSet to the Report Server, which automatically uses this DataSet to create a report that has been pre-designed for this data.

My guess is to make use of the [**Object Tab**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg3Ic.png), primarily the "*Data from DataSet, DataTables*" option in the Report Designer on our Stimulsoft Server.
After going through the Docummentation I could not find anything more about how to actually use it.

I have tried uploading a VisualStudio-DataSet(.xsd), but I can't attach the file to my report. No Errors, it just is does not let me attach to it. Other DataSources (e.g. Excel Files) do work.

What should I do? Is there another way for me to send DataSets to the Server and get a report out of it? Other connection types like SQL would work but are not relevant for this case.

> Also, we are using the trial version for now. Pretty sure this does
>   not affect my problem in any way but I'd better add this information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can add new XML connection in which specify .xml or .xsd files and then select necessary tables.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUVw7.png